# Want better search result in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to make my search result better, so for this i want that substring should also be matched. 
For example..

In Mysql query when i search `bag` in `product_name` column as an output it give me 50 results but when i search `bags` in `product_name` it give me 20 results. But i want 50 results in second case also.

```
Select * from table where product_name like %bag% 


Select * from table where product_name like %bags%
```

May be my question is duplicate but i didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Without any effort of your own, this question seems way to broad to me. Also: what do you expect to be searched for? If I enter `bags`, what will it search for? `bags` `bag` `ba` `b`... How does it know when to stop?

Comment: @T3H40 i tried with many thing like Full Text Index search and REGXP but no success

Comment: How can you expect to get 50 results, if there are only 20 rows that match `%bags%`?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to return all result whether the user enter plural or singular you can remove s or es from the keyword before search, but this way not accurate and you should make a complex function to loop all plural words rules. the best way to resolve this to help user enter 1 type in insertion process and display autocomplete if this entered before and avoid enter the same word you want to be the same twice into your database.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response but i am aware about the alternative that you suggest but i want it in mysql query not by other solutions.